# Apache Guacamole - how to open connection in a new browser tab or new browser window?

Tags: guacamole

I need some help with Apache Guacamole.

I would like some help on how to open a computer connection so that the session opens in a new browser tab or new browser window?

Thanks in advance

I looked through the guacamole docs for 1.4 and previous, also searched the web, did not find any help there.

Answer (score 1):

Holding down 'Ctrl' key when selecting the connection in guacamole. This will open up the connection in a new tab/window